# Writing a helper method for page headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently integrating twitter bootstrap.

My application layout currently includes my flash messages right above the yield:

```
    <div class="container">

            <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

            <div class="content" role="main">
                <%= render :partial => 'shared/flash', :object => flash %>
                <%= yield %>
            </div>

            <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>


    </div> <!--! end of #container -->
```

However, I am also using the bootstrap Page Headers in my individual views

```
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Sign In <small>through one of these services:</small></h1>
    </div>
```

I would like my flash messages to be below these page headers when page headers are set. So I'm thinking the best way to do this is to create a helper method and edit my application layout to be something like:

```
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

        <div class="content" role="main">
            <%= pageHeader %>
            <%= render :partial => 'shared/flash', :object => flash %>
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
```

How would I go about writing the helper for this. Would the best way to just have instance variables for @page_header and @page_header_small in my controller? Or is there a better rails way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user content_for combined with yield.

In your layout you can put this block with headline above flash message

```
<%= yield :page_header %>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/flash', :object => flash %>
<%= yield %>
```

and in your template for action

```
<% content_for :page_header do %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Sign In <small>through one of these services:</small></h1>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Check it out at [Ruby Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for)